# Writing a MP in zimpl to be solved with scip

Tags: scip

This might be a quite basic question, however, I did not find any suggestions so far.

I am running the Scip Opt Suite on OSX and everything runs well so far. No I wanted to start to model my first mathematical problem in zimpl, however I do not know how to start.

However, in the user's guide there is just prescribed how to load existing zpl-files, but not how to create on files.

Do you have any suggestions or any further threads dealing with that task?

Kind Regards

Comment: What about opening an editor, writing ZIMPL code and saving it as .zpl?

Answer (score 2):

In the zimpl package root, there's an `example` directory. The .zpl files in `example` are a great starting point for writing your own zimpl inputs. Also, zimpl's author wrote [this pdf](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/index/index/docId/884) that walks through the process of writing a formulation to solve a Sudoku puzzle using zimpl.