# How do I create a *.zpl file using zimpl?

Tags: scip

how do I create a file of the form .zpl to be used with SCIP? Do I write my problem in a notepad and save it as .zpl?

Comment: The same question has been asked two weeks ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457189/writing-a-mp-in-zimpl-to-be-solved-with-scip

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is exactly what you have to do.